# Array returns as [object, object] in most cases. What does this mean?

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays

Of the following examples, the top two return [object, object], but the third returns what I would expect from the first two, which is "Next"

```
alert(sceChoicesArr);

alert(sceChoicesArr[0]);

alert(sceChoicesArr[0].text());
```

Here's the array being created:

```
var sceChoicesArr = [];

$(xml).find('choice').each(function(){sceChoicesArr.push($(this));});
```

And here's the bit of xml it's looking for in the line above:

```
<choice>Next</choice>
```

I'm trying to spit out the array into html, and I keep writing things out off examples like the ones on this page: [Display all items in array using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541570/display-all-item-in-array-using-jquery) as well as this: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisabrams/hYQm4/ but none of these examples seem to be able to pull out the value inside the array, as when I check it out with an alert, all I'm getting is [object, object]

So my question is, what is [object, object], and why am I getting that instead of "Next"?

It seems to me that the only value of my array should equate to ["Next"]

Comment: It means it's an object, and that alerts are'nt a debugging tool.

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert`, so you can view the entire object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using `sceChoicesArr.push($(this));`. Which is pushing a **jQuery object** to the array.

`alert` is implicitly calling `Object.prototype.toString` with `sceChoicesArr`, which when called on an object, returns `"[object Object]"`.

Instead of using:

```
sceChoicesArr.push($(this));
```

use:

```
sceChoicesArr.push($(this).text());
```

And then to get the array in a "readable" form:

```
sceChoicesArr.join(", ")
```

**Or** continue pushing `$(this)`, and then to get a "readable" form, use:

```
var readableArr = $.map(sceChoicesArr, function (value, index) {
    return $(value).text();
});
```

which will return a new array with only the text of each element. Then just use:

```
readableArr.join(", ")
```

If you only want to view the contents of your array (and not use it anywhere else), you can use `console.log(sceChoicesArr);` which should provide a useful overview of your variable.

Comment: @adeneo You don't give me enough time :) And I wasn't sure if they wanted to see its contents from a developer's standpoint (looking at the screen) or needs it somewhere else in the code/page