# Display array into span with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

Trying to learn more about jQuery I have run into an issue with trying to display an inline CSS into a `<span>`.  I am trying to take an array and display it as followed:

```
<div class="colorbar">
    <span style="background: #A56AC2"></span>
    <span style="background: #E2CED7"></span>
    <span style="background: #5E5992"></span>
    <span style="background: #E4E6A2"></span>
    <span style="background: #B45748"></span>
</div><!-- end .colorbar -->
```

My array:

```
var colorArray = new Array(
    "A56AC2",
    "E2CED7",
    "5E5992",
    "B45748",
    "E4E6A2"
);
```

Ive tried:

```
 $('.colorbar').html( '<span style="background: #' + colorArray. + (';</span>'));
```

From this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541570/display-all-items-in-array-using-jquery) I assumed:

```
$('.colorbar').html( '<span style="background: #' + colorArray.join + (';</span>'));
```

and:

```
var addingHTML = [];
for ( var i=0; i < colorArray.length; i++ ) {
    addingHTML.push ('<span style="background: #' + colorArray + ';"');
}
$(".colorbar").html(addingHTML.join(""));
```

Ive looked into:

- adding [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to the `<span>` but going through the `array` Im having trouble.
- using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

However, it is not rendering correctly.  Does someone mind educating me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your third try with the for loop was almost correct. It should be `colorArray[i]` to access just the item at index `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(colorArray).each(function(i, e) {
    $('.colorbar').append('<span style="background: #' + e + '"></span>');
});
```

The [`each(index, element)`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)-function iterates all elements of a object, in your case your array `colorArray`.

In my example `i` is my name for the first argument, `index` and just contains the current position, starting at `0`.

The second argument is `element` (or short `e`, in my example) and contains the current element of your object/list/whatever. In your case: your color codes.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Do you mind explaining what the `e` does?

Comment: I updated my answer and hope you can understand it better, now. If not, just ask! :)

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO ->** http://jsfiddle.net/JBSKL/1/

By using your code..

```
var colorArray = new Array("A56AC2", "E2CED7", "5E5992", "B45748", "E4E6A2");

var addingHTML = [];
for ( var i=0; i < colorArray.length; i++ ) {
    addingHTML.push ('<span style="background: #' + colorArray[i] + '">' + i + '</span>');
}
$(".colorbar").html(addingHTML.join(""));
```

Few issues fixed

1. In your array, you have an extra comma `,` at the end
2. Use `colorArray[i]` instead of colorArray in the for loop
3. Close `span` tag in your for loop.

Comment: +1 I didnt see the extra `,` at the end of the `array()`

Comment: You don't need a comma after this `"E4E6A2",`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a cleaner approach would be to use the built-in `css` function. Also, you should build your collection of spans then append them all at once to the DOM, minimizing the number of DOM manipulations:

```
var colorArray = [
    "A56AC2",
    "E2CED7",
    "5E5992",
    "B45748",
    "E4E6A2"
];

$(function () {
  var $spans = new $();
  $.each(colorArray, function(i, e) {
      $spans = $spans.add($("<span>Howdy</span>").css("background-color", "#" + e));
  });

  $(".colorbar").append($spans);
});
```

Here the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/grinn/pen/gbuAE/).

Answer (score 0):

Life can be much easier without jQuery most of the time.

```
 var colorArray = ["A56AC2", "E2CED7", "5E5992", "B45748", "E4E6A2"];
 colorArray.forEach(color => {
     document.querySelector('.colorbar').innerHTML += '<span style="background: #' + color + '"></span>';
 });
```

Otherwise, with jQuery:

```
 var colorArray = ["A56AC2", "E2CED7", "5E5992", "B45748", "E4E6A2"];
 colorArray.forEach(color => {
      $('.colorbar').html($('.colorbar').html() + '<span style="background: #' + color + '"></span>');
 });
```